# Pub/Sub Messages lost on production

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have few topics and subscriptions on google pub/sub. I created .net core application which publish and receives messages using `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1` nuget library.
Code is pretty easy:

```
// send a message
var result = await publisher.PublishAsync(topicName, messages);
...
// receive pending messages in loop
var response = await subscriber.PullAsync(subscriptionName, true, count);
```

As I see from logs publisher successfully publish a message but subscriber never receive it. Same application does not work on cloud but works on local machine. Configuration is same on both environments (my machine get access to same Pub/Sub service as production). Is it possible somehow make a diagnostics and find out what the problem is?

Comment: do you see the message in the topic on the pubsub dashboard?

Comment: Thinking out loud ... if you have one publisher, one subscription and TWO apps using the same subscription, any single app will NOT see all the messages.  Can you elaborate on your test?  Is it one publisher?  Is it one subscription?  How many concurrent apps using that subscription?

Comment: @Kolban yes I switched off prod application while testing locally. So I have single one publisher and single one subscriber as well

Comment: did you follow this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-pub-sub.
Also, you are getting some message or is only not working?

Comment: This question caused me to think about Audit Logging using Stackdriver and I was surprised to read: "Cloud Pub/Sub doesn't write Data Access audit logs." (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/audit-logging).  This could make it quite challenging to determine the fate of a message.

Comment: I have just removed all topics and subscriptions and created them again, everything started work. I dont know why